# nodejs/mongodb, remove entire collection

Tags: mongodb, node.js

I'm trying to remove all items in a collection.

```
db.collection('sessions', function(err, collection) {                                      
    collection.remove();                 
});
```

This is the error I get:

```
node.js:134
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
        ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'getRequestId' of null
    at [object Object].executeCommand (/srv/www/www.cidev.com/nodejs/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:778:48)
    at Collection.remove (/srv/www/www.cidev.com/nodejs/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/collection.js:199:26)
    at /srv/www/www.cidev.com/nodejs/session/memory/index.js:15:20
    at [object Object].collection (/srv/www/www.cidev.com/nodejs/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:197:12)
    at new <anonymous> (/srv/www/www.cidev.com/nodejs/session/memory/index.js:14:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/www/www.cidev.com/nodejs/session/memory/index.js:157:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:411:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:302:12)
```

However, I can do this via mongodb fine:

```
db.sessions.remove();
```

What's the best way to achieve what I want via node?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Going back to this... just to update the question.

```
store.collection('sessions',function(err, collection){
    collection.remove({},function(err, removed){
    });
});
```

Comment: store is the db object

Comment: this method is now deprecated https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.3/api/Collection.html#remove better to use the answer in here https://stackoverflow.com/a/39977526/1437934

Answer (score 11):

I know this is a little late to the party and much has changed, but to [remove a collection in node](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#drop), you do this:

```
db.collection('someCollection').drop();
```

From the mongo terminal you do this:

```
db.someCollection.drop();
```

It's that simple.

Comment: what if you wanted to clear the entire collection with out dropping it ? i.e. to preserve the indexes

Answer (score 3):

Providing a more recent answer, based on API changes and trying the previous answers myself.

The following example represents a block of code as we use it in our integration tests:

```js
const mongoUrl = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test-database';
const mongoClient = await MongoClient.connect(mongoUrl, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
});

const database = mongoClient.db();
if (database) {
  const collections = await database.listCollections();
  await collections.forEach(async collection => {
    console.log(`Dropping ${collection.name}`);
    await database.collection(collection.name).drop();
  });
}
```

Note, while you could use the following, it will fail if you don't have full permissions over the database, such as in Mongo Cloud:

```js
await database.dropDatabase();
```

For context, I was using [mongodb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb) package 3.5.9 and node 14.15.1.

Comment: This is the way.

Comment: This will drop the database, but not one collection.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you were able to figure this out, but your code did not work for me...perhaps because of changes in the API? Anyway I was able to remove an entire collection's contents using the following code:

```
db.CollectionName.remove().exec(function(error) {
    if(error) {
        console.log('Uh oh: ' + error);
    }
    else {
        console.log('    [Existing Collection Deleted]');
    }
 });
```